# Como receber o resultado de uma função assincrona e passar para o return?

Tags: node.js, expressões-lambda, assincronismo

Tenho o seguinte código em nodejs numa função lambda na AWS que foi definida usando serverless.

O objetivo dessa função é ler uma URL que vai retornar um XML, transformar em JSON e fazer o display desse JSON.

Quando rodo a função consigo ver o JSON mas o return vem vazio.
Eu consigo ver o JSON pq fiz um console.log dentro da função request.

Como eu faço para poder recuperar a resposta dentro do return?

```
'use strict';

module.exports.hello = async (event, context) => {

    let jsonResp='';
    //Retrieve XML form the URL
    var request = require('request');
    request('https://URL_q_retorn_XML', function (error, response, body) {
        //COnvert XML into JSON
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            let xmlParser = '';
            xmlParser = require('xml2json');
            jsonResp = xmlParser.toJson(body);
            console.log('JSON output',jsonResp);

            //TODO retrieve s3 object and insert JSON inside it.
            require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');

        }
        else {
            console.log("Error "+response.statusCode)
        }
    })


    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: jsonResp,
    };

  // Use this code if you don't use the http event with the LAMBDA-PROXY integration
  // return { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event };
};
```

Comment: O que dá `console.log(body);`?

Comment: o xml que vem da URL

Comment: Essa API `request()` tem Promises? ou seja em vez de callback podes usar `await request('https://URL_q_retorn_XML');`?

Comment: Essa API `request()` tem Promises? ou seja em vez de callback podes usar `await request('https://URL_q_retorn_XML');`?

Comment: sei que é algo com o assincronismo. pois o return vem primeiro e a variavel jsonResp vem vazia. Teria que fazer o return vir depois do request.

Comment: tentei usar wait mas nao sei como. Eu sou programador backend. :)

Comment: Eu percebo bem o problema, a minha pergunta é se a API do request tem Promises, pois assim resolves o problema usando `await`. Qual é o link para a documentação desse `request`?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request usa promise

Comment: Se está usando async pode utilizar await antes de sentar a variável que será passada no return

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precisas de retornar uma promise, mas no caso do `request` a API não suporta promises. Uma alternativa seria usar o https://github.com/request/request-promise-native que não é mantido há mais de um ano :(

Assim só vejo uma solução, criar uma Promise que fique à espera do resultado, e ser essa Promise o `return` da função:

```js
'use strict';

const request = require('request');
const xmlParser = require('xml2json');

module.exports.hello = async(event, context) => {
  // Retrieve XML form the URL
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request('https://URL_q_retorn_XML', function(error, response, body) {
      // Convert XML into JSON
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const jsonResp = xmlParser.toJson(body);
        console.log('JSON output', jsonResp);
        resolve({
          statusCode: response.statusCode,
          body: jsonResp,
        });
      } else {
        console.log("Error " + response.statusCode);
        reject(response.statusCode);
      }
    })
  });
};
```